# Jquery scroll to top animate

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I know this question has been asked and answered a lot but even with that I can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong. I'm trying to create a scrollTop animation using the "back to top" button at the end of the page but it doesn't seem to be working.

The code is as follows:

HTML

```
<h2 class="bottom-border extra-bottom-margin"><a href="#" class="go-to-top">Back to top</a></h2>.
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".go-to-top").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop": "0px"}, 100);
})
});
</script>
```

The URL is http://mike-griffin.com/about-me.html

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar that is appearing belongs to your .container element, not the body.

Observe the behavior when you remove the css property:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

from the .container style.

Or to fix:

```
<script>

    $(".go-to-top").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".container").animate({"scrollTop": "0px"}, 100);
    })

 </script>
```

Comment: Ah I see... I work when that is removed however it then messes up the layout of some elements... is there a work around? can I modify the jquery to effect the scroll bar of the container? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: See update: $(".container").animate({"scrollTop": "0px"}, 100);

Comment: Ah i've just done that, works perfectly and I've learned a little more about Jquery, thank you! I don't have the reputation to up vote :( thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted here should work, but that's not the code that you have on your website.

On the website you have this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".go-to-top").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("body").animate({"scrollTop": "0px"}, 1000);
    })
});
```

To make it work, change `$("body")` to `$("html, body")`. Reason for this is browser compatibility - some browsers apply the scroll position to `document.documentElement` (*html*) while others apply it to `document.body` (*body*).

Comment: Thanks for your help I've just applied it to the .container element and seem to be working perfectly now, thank you!